# “to find a friend to practice speaking with" or "finding a friend to practice speaking with"?

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, syntax, infinitive-vs-gerund

In the following conversation:

> --- Did you have any problems in your English study?
> --- Yes, _____ a friend to practice speaking with.

Is it correct to fill in the blank with "**to find**” Or "**finding**"?

The answer is "finding," but I think both would  be correct. What's the difference between the two, infinitive and gerund?

Comment: We don't say: in your English study. That would mean a library in a private house done in an English style....have problems when studying English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Finding* is **much** more idiomatic there than *to find*.

I believe that this is because the omitted headword is *problem*. *Problem* normally takes an *-ing* clause as its complement, not a *to* clause.

So

> We had a problem finding anybody.

is much more common than

> ?We had a problem to find anybody.

The iWeb corpus has 3977 instances of *problem finding*, and only 521 of *problem to find*; but actually the disparity is greater than that, because in many of the latter, *to find* is not actually the complement of *problem*, for example "we don't need to finish the long division problem to find the remainder".

As usual with such questions, there is no rule or logic to this: it's just the way that the word *problem* happens to work.

Comment: Why not state outright that find is really not idiomatic or grammatical here.

Comment: @Lambie Why is "to find" not grammatical? I don't think so from what I've learned: infinitives can act as a complement to nouns, also as Colin states

Comment: @HypnoticBuggyWraithVirileBevy: this is a much-discussed argument about just what "grammatical" means. Is it enough that a particular structure is allowed there in general, or does it also require that the particular words (in this case _problem_) license the use of that structure here? You take the first view, Lambie the second.

Comment: @HypnoticBuggyWraithVirileBevy It is isn't idiomatic in this context. I have a problem (finding a friend to practice with). Finding a fried to practice with is not easy. Compare that to this answer: I have a problem to find a friend to practice with. [buzzer]